# How do I make this part of the kettle?

Tags: edit-mode

This is the image I am basing my model on:
[image]

How can I recreate such part of the kettle where the red arrow is pointing at (I'm just a beginner and don't know much).
Here is the current model I have:
[image]

I have had 2 solutions that did not work:

1. Create a new part and snap it to the model to recreate the given part or the part inside the red outline.

Problem: It doesn't align with the vertices, edges and faces of the model.

2. Extrude from an existing part and then try to recreate it.

Problem: They don't align and the model looks really bad when this is applied.

Is there any solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also use extrusion:

Select some of the faces:

[image]

Extrude and move, scale, etc:

[image]